# Why does variable suddenly get out of scope ? (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

still learning python.

In this code, I can reference `v0` and `v1` to compute `v2` inside the `Foo` class. So far, so good.

```py
class Foo():

  v0="abcd"
  v1="efgh"
  v2=(v0, v1)
  #v3=[(v0, c) for c in v2]     # NameError: name 'v0' is not defined.
  #v3=[("abcd", c) for c in v2] # Works

print(Foo.v0, Foo.v1, Foo.v2)
#print(Foo.v0, Foo.v1, Foo.v2, Foo.v3)
```

But if I uncomment the `v3=[(v0, c) for c in v2]` line, I get an error that states `v0` is not defined.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/machin.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo():
  File "/private/tmp/machin.py", line 6, in Foo
    v3=[(v0, c) for c in v2]
  File "/private/tmp/machin.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    v3=[(v0, c) for c in v2]
NameError: name 'v0' is not defined. Did you mean: '.0'?
```

Strangely enough, `v2` does not receive the same treatment and this line works :

```
    v3=[("abcd", c) for c in v2]
```

Reading the python doc about [classes, scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) does not help me to understand what is happening...

So questions :

1. Why is the variable `v0` suddenly out of scope but `v2` is still reachable ?
2. Is there a workaround that does not involve retyping the `v0` literal again ? Which one ?

Comment: This is a weird edge case. Essentially, list comprehensions use a local, function scope. But class blocks *do not create enclosing scopes* (this is why you cannot access a variable in a class block from a function/method directly, you have to use `self.whatever`). See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: `v2` is still reachable because the leftmost for-clause is evaluated in *the scope where the list comprehension is executed*, not in it's internal scope. It works essentially like passing whatever is in `for x in <whatever>` to a function (this is literally what happens underneath the hood, examine the dissasembly of a list comprehension using the `dis` module)

Comment: Thanks both of you, Juanpa.Arrivallaga and @khelwood. I did not find the linked question that is exactly the same as mine. What should I do now ? just delete the my question, or leave it here ?

Comment: It's fine to leave it, but it's up to you